# Magento : Shipping rules takes grand total excluding taxes for Subtotal

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shopping-cart, rules

I use shipping rules to set up a list of different post options. I had to create two rules in order to provide free shipping for all orders within UK over £60. So I created these two rules.

Rule one: 
 If ALL of these conditions are TRUE: Subtotal less than 60.00 Shipping Country is one of United Kingdom

Rule two:
 If ALL of these conditions are TRUE: Subtotal greater than or equal to 60.00 Shipping Country is one of United Kingdom

But I noticed that the shipping cost still appears on some orders with total over £60 and within the UK. I looked into it and noticed that when Grand total Excl. Tax is under £60 rule one is applied and with the shipping cost and when Grand total Excl. Tax is over £60 rule two is applied and with out the shipping cost.

What confused me the most is that it says cart subtotal when you set up rules. I wonder what could be a possible solution for such problem?

Comment: For a quick fix I used a grand subtotal price that the shop would give to me when my total was 60. So I had to replace figure 60 in my rules to 51.32. This is not the right way to do it. But it is an easy fix and Could to the job till I find the proper way to fix it.

Comment: All shipping in magento looks at the tax-exclusive and non-discounted total by default. This is what's known as the subtotal, the grand total takes into account all the other factors including shipping cost.